# Removing spam from a database using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written the following in NodeJS as I am trying to learn a bit more about that toolset. It 'works' but is not very robust. I am not concerned with security at this stage and the code will not be accessible to end users. I would like to incorporate some kind of timer which ensures that the call to the Akismet API does not hit a rate limit. Occasionally I see socket hang up and timeout errors.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '123',
    database : 'mydb',
    //debug: true,
    multipleStatements: true
});

var akismet = require('akismet').client({ blog: 'http://example.com', apiKey: 'xxxxxxx' });

var selectPosts = "SELECT p.topic_id as id, poster_ip, t.subject as message, p.poster FROM topics  t\
                  LEFT JOIN posts p on t.first_post_id = p.id WHERE poster_ip != ''";

akismet.verifyKey(function(err, verified) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if (verified) {

        console.log('API key successfully verified.');
    }

    else {

        console.log('Unable to verify API key.');
    }

});

connection.connect();

connection.query(selectPosts, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    rows.forEach( function(entry) {

    checkSpam(entry)

    });

});

var afterDelete = function (err, result) {

    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('deleted ' + result.affectedRows + ' rows');


}

var afterCheck = function(err, entry) {

    if (err) throw err;

    var deleteQuery = "DELETE t, p FROM topics AS t LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON t.id = p.topic_id WHERE t.id=";
    var deleteUser = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username='"+entry.poster+"';";
        console.log(deleteQuery + entry.id);
        console.log('entry is ' + entry['id']);
        connection.query(deleteQuery + entry.id, function(err,result)
        {
            afterDelete(err,result);
        });

        connection.query(deleteUser, afterDelete);



}

var checkSpam = function(entry) {
    akismet.checkSpam({
        user_ip: entry['poster_ip'],
        comment_author: entry['poster'],
        comment_content: entry['message']

    }, function(err, spam){
        if (err) throw err;
        if (spam) {
            //console.log('spam');
            afterCheck(err, entry);

        } else {

            console.log('Not spam');

        }

    });


}

//connection.end();
```

Comment: You have an SQL injection vulnerability.  Use prepared statements instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code can use a little formatting. I usually go with 2-character indents (tabs or spaces) since in JS, code tends to be nested. I usually also limit my newlines to 1 or 2, one being a "breather" and 2 for totally different blocks of code. While everyone's preferences vary, always consider consistency and readability.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '123',
    database : 'mydb',
    //debug: true,
    multipleStatements: true
});

var akismet = require('akismet').client({ blog: 'http://example.com', apiKey: 'xxxxxxx' });
```

I suggest you read your credentials from environment variables. You wouldn't want anyone seeing your passwords or API keys, especially when you start to use a version control system. This also makes it easy for multiple deployments (multiple machines, virtual hosts etc) as the credentials can be configured from a provisioning tool. I doubt your host will always be `localhost` on every machine, or your database be named `mydb` on every instance, or your API key be just one across your system.

```
const POSTS_QUERY = `
  SELECT
    p.topic_id as id,
    poster_ip,
    t.subject as message,
    p.poster
  FROM
    topics
  LEFT JOIN
    posts p on t.first_post_id = p.id 
  WHERE
    poster_ip != ''
`;
```

If you're using the newer Node.js (I believe the 4.x onwards), it should have ES6 support, which includes multi-line (backticked) strings. This allows you to write SQL queries like the one above. Much cleaner than your single-lined strings. And since it's probably a constant string, I suggest using `const` as well as a conventional all-caps, snake-cased name.

I notice that your async functions are "node functions" (receive an error object first, data second). You can take advantage of [Bluebird's `promisify` function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) to turn them into Promise-returning functions. That way, you can take advantage of Promises and write fairly linear-looking code.

Here's an excerpt of what I came up with:

```
let Promise = require("bluebird");

let connection = require('mysql').createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '123',
  database: 'mydb',
  //debug: true,
  multipleStatements: true
});

let akismet = require('akismet').client({
  blog: 'http://example.com',
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxx'
});

const SELECT_POSTS = `
  SELECT
    p.topic_id as id,
    poster_ip,
    t.subject as message,
    p.poster
  FROM
    topics
  LEFT JOIN
    posts p on t.first_post_id = p.id 
  WHERE
    poster_ip != ''
`;

let verifyKey = Promise.promisify(akismet.verifyKey);
let query = Promise.promisify(connection.query, { multiargs: true });
let checkSpam = Promise.promisify(akismet.checkSpam);

let verifyKeyPromise = verifyKey()
.then(function(verified){
  console.log('API key successfully verified');
  connection.connect()
  return query(SELECT_POSTS);
}, function(err){
  console.log('Unable to verify API key');
})
.then(function(rows, fields){
  console.log('Posts retrieved');
  return Promise.all(rows.map(function(entry){
    return checkSpam({
      user_ip: entry['poster_ip'],
      comment_author: entry['poster'],
      comment_content: entry['message']
    });
  });
}, function(v){
  console.log('Failed to retrieve posts');
})
.then(function(entrySpamStatus){
  console.log('Spam check succeeded');
  // and so on...  
}, function(err){
  console.log('Spam check failed');
  // and so on...  
})

// and so on...
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Do you have any advice on the timer / rate limit issue?